# Metatable issue

Tags: lua, metatable

So I know that lua will look to a table's metatable if it doesn't contain the variable I reference, but it seems wrong that when I attempt to set a variable that doesn't exist yet in a table it sets it in the metatable instead.

Heres an example of what i mean

```
a = {__index = {tbl1 = {var = 1}, tbl2 = {var = 2}}}
b = setmetatable({}, a)
print(b.tbl1.var, a.__index.tbl1.var)
b.tbl1.var = 2
print(b.tbl1.var, a.__index.tbl1.var)
```

In this code it will replace the metatables variable instead of setting it in the table im referencing.

However this does not occur with this code

```
a = {__index = {4, 5, 6}}
b = setmetatable({}, a)
print(b[1], a.__index[1])
b[1] = 2
print(b[1], a.__index[1])
```

Is there more work needed when using metatables and nested tables?
Or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this code it will replace the metatables variable instead of setting it in the table im referencing.

I think this is to be expected; the code retrieves `tbl1` key and sets a field in the table associated with that key. The key doesn't exist in the table, only in the metatable, so that's where it's set. If you add the same key in the table `b = setmetatable({tbl1 = {}}, a)`, you'll see that the value is set in that table.

> Is there more work needed when using metatables and nested tables? Or is there a way around this?

I'm not sure what result you expect. Lua doesn't do [autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification), which would make `tbl.foo = 1` to create table `tbl` if it didn't already exist. If the field `tbl1` is already present in the table, the the behavior is exactly what you'd expect. If it's present in the metatable, and you modify its field, this is exactly where it's going to be modified.

Comment: If I use     b = setmetatable({tbl1 = {}}, a), it does not inherit the metatables value and instead returns nil which defeats the purpose of the metatable in this context.

Comment: That's exactly what you get: if you don't have tbl1 key in your table, you get its default value (from the metatable). If you try to modify values in the table you got based on tbl1 key reference, those will be modified in that table. That's why I asked what you are trying to do or avoid. If you want to avoid modifications to the table stored as value for tbl1 key, you may need to set a metatable on that table.